# Inverted pyramid on c++

Tags: c++

how to make the output reverse? I've tried it several times but always failed

so far my code looks something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows, number = 1, space;

    cin >> rows;

    for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for(space = 1; space <= rows-i; ++space)
        {
            cout <<"  ";
        }

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            cout << number << "   ";
            ++number;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

> ```
>       1
>     2   3
>   4   5   6
> 7   8   9   10
> ```

Comment: Instead of printing from lower to higher, print from higher to lower.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Show us the Reverse Output you are after

Comment: In case you think folks are messing with you by asking you for the inverted pyramid, they're not. Odds are really good that by typing the sucker out you'll have that special moment of clarity where it all makes sense. If you can type it out, you just have to translate what you did to print it out into a few loops and print statements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows,space;

    cin >> rows;

    int number=0;
    int x = 1;

    while(x<=rows)
    {
        number=number+x;
        x++;
    }   


    for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for(space = 1; space <i; ++space)
        {
            cout <<"  ";
        }

        for(int j = i; j <= rows; ++j)
        {
            cout << number << "   ";
            --number;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if by inverted you mean this,

```
10   9   8   7   
  6   5   4   
    3   2   
      1
```

then above is the code for that. You need to find out the largest number for given number of rows, in this case it is 10 and then little modifications in your code to meet the requirement.

Comment: @Downvoter, please give the reason for it as it will help me in improving the answer

Comment: You did someone's homework for them. One day you may have to work beside someone who cut-n-pasted their way through school. It's not much fun.